# How to perform exponent action in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

Currently, i am using robot framework on top of python. I want to perform an exponent operation something like as follows:

```
${result}  Evaluate  Pow(2,3)
```

The expected value stored for `${result}` in this case is `8`.

Note: `Pow(,)` function is a placeholder. I need some function/keyword to perform exponent operation.

Comment: The expression is evaluated in python so use `2**3`

Answer (score 3):

> I need some function/keyword to perform exponent operation.

There are many ways to do this, I'm not exactly sure what you're expecting.

To use evaluate, use python's exponentiation operator `**`. For example:

```
*** Test cases ***
Test raw expression
    ${result}=  evaluate  2**3
    should be equal as numbers  ${result}  8
```

Here's a very basic "pow" keyword:

```
*** Keywords ***
pow
    [Arguments]  ${base}  ${exponent}
    ${result}=  evaluate  int($base)**int($exponent)
    [Return]    ${result}
```

Here is an example of usage:

```
*** Test cases ***
Test "Pow 2**3"
    ${result}=  pow  2  3
    should be equal as numbers  ${result}  8
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, i have used pow() function provided by inbuilt python libraries. That is working for me. Thanks for the reply.